# How to override Azure App Configuration in Integration test

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using the mvc integration test package to test my application.

I am also using azure app configuration for ... configuration.

In my integration tests, I do not want to use all the possible credentials from `DefaultAzureCredential`. I only want it to use `EnvironmentCredential`.

I've tried overriding the options as you see below, but when I run the tests in Azure Devops pipeline it keeps trying to use the excluded credentials. So I assume my override is not working as I want to.

Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                    {
                        var startupConfig = config.Build();
                        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(
                            azureConfiguration =>
                            {
                                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                                azureConfiguration.Connect(startupConfig.GetValue<Uri>("Configuration:Url"), credential)
                                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
                                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, startupConfig["Configuration:Environment"])
                                    .ConfigureKeyVault(opts => opts.SetCredential(credential));
                            });
                    });
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Test

```
        public DefaultControllerTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, conf) =>
                {
                    // var startupConfig = conf.Build();
                    // conf.AddAzureAppConfiguration(
                    //     azureConfiguration =>
                    //     {
                    //         // Exkludera shared token cache för den har problem i pipeline
                    //         var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
                    //         {
                    //             ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
                    //             ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true
                    //         });
                    //         azureConfiguration.Connect(startupConfig.GetValue<Uri>("Configuration:Url"), credential)
                    //             .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
                    //             .Select(KeyFilter.Any, startupConfig["Configuration:Environment"])
                    //             .ConfigureKeyVault(opts => opts.SetCredential(credential));
                    //     });

                    var projectDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                    conf.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(projectDir, "testsettings.json"));
                    conf.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(projectDir, "testsettings.development.json"), true);

                    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.Configure<DefaultAzureCredentialOptions>(opts =>
                        {
                            opts.ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true;
                            opts.ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true;
                        });
                    });

                    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.Configure<DefaultAzureCredentialOptions>(opts =>
                        {
                            opts.ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true;
                            opts.ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        //
        // [Fact]
        // public async Task ProtectedEndpointReturns401IfUnauthenticated()
        // {
        //     // Arrange
        //     var client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient(new UnauthenticatedHttpMessageHandler());
        //
        //     // Act
        //     var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/protected"));
        //
        //     // Assert
        //     Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, result.StatusCode);
        // }

        [Fact]
        public async Task ProtectedEndpointReturns200IfAuthenticated()
        {
            // Arrange
            using var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
            var handler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BearerHttpMessageHandler>();
            var client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient(handler);

            // Act
            var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/protected"));

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
        }
```

A typical error from devops pipeline:

```
2023-03-23T12:56:53.4175806Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2023-03-23T12:56:53.4583546Z A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
2023-03-23T12:57:01.9336451Z [xUnit.net 00:00:06.42]     Test.System.Boilerplate.Controllers.DefaultControllerTest.ProtectedEndpointReturns200IfAuthenticated [FAIL]
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1904066Z   Failed Test.System.Boilerplate.Controllers.DefaultControllerTest.ProtectedEndpointReturns200IfAuthenticated [5 s]
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1905504Z   Error Message:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1906805Z    Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException : DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1908060Z - EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1909138Z - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1909870Z Status: 400 (Bad Request)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1910062Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1910409Z Content:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1910892Z {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1911163Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1911508Z Headers:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1911915Z Server: IMDS/150.870.65.949
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1912403Z Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2023 12:56:57 GMT
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1912999Z Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1913533Z Content-Length: 68
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1913707Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1914370Z - Operating system Linux 5.15.0-1034-azure #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 10 19:59:45 UTC 2023 isn't supported.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1915169Z - Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1915794Z - Please run 'az login' to set up account
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1917125Z ---- System.AggregateException : Multiple exceptions were encountered while attempting to authenticate. (EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.) (ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1918510Z Status: 400 (Bad Request)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1918712Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1919064Z Content:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1919559Z {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1919833Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1920184Z Headers:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1920594Z Server: IMDS/150.870.65.949
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1921070Z Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2023 12:56:57 GMT
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1921673Z Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1922182Z Content-Length: 68
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1923241Z ) (Operating system Linux 5.15.0-1034-azure #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 10 19:59:45 UTC 2023 isn't supported.) (Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account.) (Please run 'az login' to set up account)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1924510Z -------- Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException : EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1925672Z -------- Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException : ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1926433Z Status: 400 (Bad Request)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1926624Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1926979Z Content:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1927477Z {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1927756Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1928103Z Headers:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1928510Z Server: IMDS/150.870.65.949
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1928996Z Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2023 12:56:57 GMT
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1929571Z Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1930084Z Content-Length: 68
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1930275Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1931102Z -------- Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException : Operating system Linux 5.15.0-1034-azure #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 10 19:59:45 UTC 2023 isn't supported.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1932189Z -------- Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException : Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account.
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1933464Z ------------ System.InvalidOperationException : An error was encountered while reading secret from keyring, domain:'95', code:'2', message:'The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files'
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1934696Z -------- Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException : Please run 'az login' to set up account
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1935266Z   Stack Trace:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1939095Z      at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1940218Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1941071Z    at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1941861Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1942767Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1943771Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueFromCredentialAsync(TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1944841Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1945821Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1946956Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AuthenticateAndAuthorizeRequestAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1947856Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1948686Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1949621Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1950418Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1951308Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.UserAgentHeaderPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1952197Z    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1953086Z    at Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.ConfigurationClient.GetConfigurationSettingsPageAsync(SettingSelector selector, String pageLink, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1954018Z    at Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)+MoveNext()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1955004Z    at Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1955922Z    at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1956632Z    at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1957477Z    at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1958424Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass26_2.<<LoadAll>b__3>d.MoveNext()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1959358Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1960070Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass26_2.<<LoadAll>b__3>d.MoveNext()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1960976Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1961837Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.TracingUtils.CallWithRequestTracing(Boolean tracingEnabled, RequestType requestType, RequestTracingOptions requestTracingOptions, Func`1 clientCall)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1962933Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.LoadAll(Boolean ignoreFailures, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1963808Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.Load()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1964524Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1965162Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1965778Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1966366Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1967006Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1967787Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.DelegatedWebApplicationFactory.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1968607Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.ConfigureHostBuilder(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1969419Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1970068Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.get_Services()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1970998Z    at Test.System.Boilerplate.Controllers.DefaultControllerTest.ProtectedEndpointReturns200IfAuthenticated() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/test/Test.System.Boilerplate/Controllers/DefaultControllerTest.cs:line 89
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1971927Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1972458Z ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1972662Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1973244Z ----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException) -----
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1973890Z    at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1974702Z    at Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1975607Z    at Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1976581Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1977541Z ----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException) -----
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1978376Z    at Azure.Identity.ImdsManagedIdentitySource.HandleResponseAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, Response response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1979355Z    at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1980269Z    at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1981203Z    at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1982017Z    at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1982816Z    at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1983729Z    at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1984801Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1985770Z ----- Inner Stack Trace #3 (Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException) -----
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1986410Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.GetTokenProviderPath()
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1987190Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1987990Z    at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1988775Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1989797Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1990772Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1991719Z ----- Inner Stack Trace #4 (Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException) -----
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1992408Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential.GetStoredCredentials(String environmentName)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1993328Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1994152Z    at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1994952Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1995883Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1996869Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1997673Z ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1998260Z    at Azure.Identity.LinuxNativeMethods.HandleError(IntPtr errorPtr, String errorMessage)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.1999153Z    at Azure.Identity.LinuxNativeMethods.secret_password_lookup_sync(IntPtr schemaPtr, IntPtr cancellable, String attribute1Type, String attribute1Value, String attribute2Type, String attribute2Value)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2000127Z    at Azure.Identity.LinuxVisualStudioCodeAdapter.LookupPassword(IntPtr& schemaPtr, String serviceName, String accountName)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2000918Z    at Azure.Identity.LinuxVisualStudioCodeAdapter.GetCredentials(String serviceName, String accountName)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2001655Z    at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential.GetStoredCredentials(String environmentName)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2002422Z ----- Inner Stack Trace #5 (Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException) -----
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2003208Z    at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.RequestCliAccessTokenAsync(Boolean async, String[] scopes, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2004108Z    at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2004900Z    at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2005683Z    at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2006567Z    at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2007610Z    at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2077594Z Results File: /home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az363-422_2023-03-23_12_57_02.trx
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2077983Z 
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2081639Z Attachments:
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2082654Z   /home/vsts/work/_temp/e4623c5b-bfad-4fa6-a3cd-3b047b090467/coverage.cobertura.xml
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2132832Z Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:     0, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: < 1 ms - /home/vsts/work/1/s/test/Test.System.Boilerplate/bin/Debug/net6.0/Test.System.Boilerplate.dll (net6.0)
2023-03-23T12:57:02.2489335Z ##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 1
```

How can I override the app configuration and the credential in my integration tests?

Related resources:
https://blog.markvincze.com/overriding-configuration-in-asp-net-core-integration-tests/